# Simpler way of saying "Converts quantitative to qualitative data"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, differences, synonyms

Words qualitative and quantitative, are in my opinion, a little difficult to read and explain for a certain audiences, explaining why there are so many discussion about it on stack exchange.

If a person were to read a tweet or post and rate it on a scale of 1 to 5 based level of verbosity, she is converting a qualitative sentence to quantitative data.

Reading a college application and either rejecting or approving it is again some level of qualitative information transformed into quantitative.

My daughter uses snapchat for 20 minutes a day is a quantitative assessment which could be represented as "medium" usage qualitatively, of course after comparing other's usage.

What would be easier to understand terms for expressing "converting quantitative information to qualitative"?

Comment: [Binning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning), as in 1 to 5 scales or high-medium-low, isn't automatically qualitative. If defined based on quantity ranges, the bins are still quantitative. Compare with "rate your pain on a 1 to 10 scale". Here, the binning is clearly qualitative.

Comment: Dickey, you're wrong to call the tweet "qualitative". It's simply data.  *Statements about the tweet* could be qualitative ("too wordy") or quantitative ("it contains 217 words").

Answer (score 3):

Converting quantitative data into qualitative information is sometimes called **interpreting the data**.  See, for example, [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/interpret?s=t):

> verb (used with object)
>
> ```
> 1   to give or provide the meaning of; explain; explicate; elucidate:
> ```

or [Encyclopedia.com](https://www.encyclopedia.com/education/news-wires-white-papers-and-books/data-collection-and-interpretation):

> Data interpretation is part of daily life for most people. Interpretation is the process of making sense of numerical data that has been collected, analyzed, and presented.